# Deciphering contents of a .replace() parameter

Tags: javascript, replace

In an example piece of code, I stumbled upon this line:

// Change the string into lower case and remove  all non-alphanumeric characters
                var cstr = str_entry.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g,'');

I think I understand that the /g inside the parameter makes everything in between the // become empty strings (''). Am I correct?

What does the ^ part of the parameter do? What does everything inside the  [ ] brackets mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of the `replace` function is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which is a way of determining if a string matches a complex pattern.

The `/g` parameter means 'global', so if two parts of the `str_entry` string match, they will both replaced with an empty string, instead of just the first one.

The `^` within `[]` means 'not', so it's saying 'check if the string is not `a-zA-Z0-9`'.

More simply, the regular expression is identifying any non-alphanumeric characters in your string. Using it with `replace(..., '')` will remove those characters.

Take a look at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) for more information about how regular expressions work. You can punch in your regular expression and it will tell you what each part of it does.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Another question about .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g,''): Does this basically mean everything that isn't ^a-zA-Z0-9 become empty or deleted? Including a space in between 2 strings for example?

Comment: [Regex101](https://regex101.com) is built for testing this sort of thing, check out this [test I setup using your regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/9sqvJS/1). Anything that the regular expression matches (in blue) will be replaced with an empty string. When using with `replace`, my test string would become `HelloworldthisisMYteststring`